# Secp256k1 solidity contract assembly errors: SyntaxError: loop flag outdated. Please consider using "switch", "if" or "for" statements instead

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm working on updating some smart contracts to deploy on the Ethereum blockchain, however the cryptographic primitive for this project are really outdated and I don't know enough about cryptography to update them. Can anyone help me to rewrite the code? The repo is here -> [[https://github.com/kCox96/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Secp256k1_noconflict.sol]](https://github.com/kCox96/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Secp256k1_noconflict.sol)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't write your own crypto!

If you just want to verify ecdsa-signatures you can use `ecrecover()` a builtin function to verify signatures, or this library https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/cryptography/ECDSA.sol

If you **really need** these curve functions there are some libraries out there (e.g. https://github.com/tdrerup/elliptic-curve-solidity) but they also seem to be not well maintained